# Python NameError for Sqlite connection

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am building a GUI based python application using Tkinter and Sqlite as a database. On the homepage (a Tkinter Window), there are multiple options from which the user can choose one and it would land him on a
new Tkinter Window where he can customise and execute a SQL query. In  the code snippet, I have added only Quer1.py.

When I run Query1.py separately , the GUI and the Sqlite conection works perfectly.
But, when I try to run it from the Homepage.py window, I run into `NameError: name 'sqliteConnection' is not defined` in `Query1.py` being called inside the `get_all_data()` function.

The sqlite connection output in the main function works perfectly giving me the SQL version but the code breaks when I call it inside the function.

Any suggestions to work around this issue ?

Query1.py

```
from SqlConnection import sqliteConnection

def get_all_data():
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    sqlite_select_Query = ("some sql query")
    cursor.execute(sqlite_select_Query)
    data = (row for row in cursor.fetchall())
    cursor.close()
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Window Title")
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    sqlite_select_Query = "select sqlite_version();"
    cursor.execute(sqlite_select_Query)
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    print("SQLite Database Version is: ", record)
    btn = Button(window, text='Fetch Query1', command=get_all_data)
    btn.grid(column=1, row=1)
    window.mainloop()
    sqliteConnection.close()
```

Homepage.py

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk    
import Query1

def get_Q1():
    exec(open('Query1.py').read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Homepage")
    window.geometry('1000x700')
    btn1 = Button(window, text='1. Orchestra(s)+country', height=7, width=60, command=get_Q1)
    btn1.grid(column=1, row=1)
    window.mainloop()
```

SqlConnection.py

```
import sqlite3
try:
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('test_1.db')
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    print("Database created and Successfully Connected to SQLite")

    sqlite_select_Query = "select sqlite_version();"
    cursor.execute(sqlite_select_Query)
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    print("SQLite Database Version is: ", record)
    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Error while connecting to sqlite", error)
```

Output

```
Database created and Successfully Connected to SQLite
SQLite Database Version is:  [('3.28.0',)]
SQLite Database Version is:  [('3.28.0',)]
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stanl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<string>", line 6, in get_all_data
NameError: name 'sqliteConnection' is not defined
```

Comment: Post the error! It works fine on my machine

Comment: @LinuxGeek I have added 2 missing lines in the Query1.py part and also pasted the output.